# Unable to use associative array value in sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to iteratively search and replace strings in a file using a variable input and replacement string. I have tried using sed and awk and have seemed to determine that it is actually the associative array value that is giving me issues(?).

I am looking at an associative array like this:

```
declare -A speedReplaceValuePairsText
speedReplaceValuePairsText["20"]="xthirtyx"
speedReplaceValuePairsText["30"]="xfiftyx"
speedReplaceValuePairsText["40"]="xsixtyx"
speedReplaceValuePairsText["50"]="xeightyx"
speedReplaceValuePairsText["60"]="xhundredx"
```

and for ease I was declaring my replacement vars first:

```
for speedBeforeValue in "${!speedReplaceValuePairsText[@]}";
do
    findValue=${speedBeforeValue}
    replaceWithValue=${speedReplaceValuePairsText[$speedBeforeValue]}
    #replaceWithValue="blah"
        
    echo "  Replacing $findValue with $replaceWithValue..."
        
    awk -v srch="$findValue" -v repl="$replaceWithValue" '{gsub(srch,repl); print}' infile.txt > outfile.txt

    #sed 's/'"$findValue"'/'"$replaceWithValue"'/g' infile.txt > outfile.txt
        
    #sed "s/$findValue/$replaceWithValue/g" $scriptDir/$currentFileName > outfile.txt
    done
```

The commented out lines are alternate versions of what I have tried with similar inbetween versions.

I have tried using just a normal string (the commented out "blah") and that works fine.

The weirdest part is that the echo statement displays the right value for both key and value.

I have tried so many combinations I am losing my mind. Please someone tell me I am doing something dumb here.

NOTE: This is nested inside another loop but I do not believe this to be an issue, let me know if I am wrong

EDIT: I have simplified the in and out files, and to clarify, if i try to use my associative array value, nothing gets replaced. But if i use a dummy string like "blah" it works.

BONUS: I have marked the answer below, but my search and replace values start and end in double quotes but no matter what I try it replaces all instances of 60. How can i make it replace "60" with "xsixtyx"?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you want help with? All your question says is that you have "issues" and that "a normal string works fine" but there's no clue so far to what problem you're actually having.

Comment: The code "looks" fine. You say "Unable to use associative array" - how have you determinated that you are unable to use them? What happened? What did not happen?

Comment: Run the code with bash -x to see how the variables are expanding line by line

Comment: please update the question with your sample input file (`$scriptDir/$currentFileName`), the (wrong) output generated by your script, and the (correct) desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `>>` instead of `>` inside your loop?

```
awk -v srch="$findValue" -v repl="$replaceWithValue" '{gsub(srch,repl); print}' $scriptDir/$currentFileName >> ./$outputFolderName/$currentFileName
```

I tried to run your code it works as expected except that `>`.

Or if you just want to see the replaced results

```
awk -v srch="$findValue" -v repl="$replaceWithValue" '{ if (gsub(srch,repl))  print}' $scriptDir/$currentFileName >> ./$outputFolderName/$currentFileName
```

For a file with

```
30
20
60
```

the output looks like

```
xthirtyx
xhundredx
xfiftyx
```

For the second case.

Here is the full bash script I tried

```
    #!/bin/bash

    declare -A speedReplaceValuePairsText
    speedReplaceValuePairsText["20"]="xthirtyx"
    speedReplaceValuePairsText["30"]="xfiftyx"
    speedReplaceValuePairsText["40"]="xsixtyx"
    speedReplaceValuePairsText["50"]="xeightyx"
    speedReplaceValuePairsText["60"]="xhundredx"

    for speedBeforeValue in "${!speedReplaceValuePairsText[@]}";
    do
            findValue=${speedBeforeValue}
            replaceWithValue=${speedReplaceValuePairsText[$speedBeforeValue]}
            echo "  Replacing $findValue with $replaceWithValue..."

            awk -v srch="$findValue" -v repl="$replaceWithValue" '{if (gsub(srch,repl)) print}' test.txt  >> /tmp/test.txt
    done
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. I was hoping it was something dumb. Quick googling didnt result in any reason why. Do you know why I need >> vs > for future reference?